# Using repository inside a form request on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

So I find myself [creating form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#creating-form-requests) to validate the request that has been posted from a form. And sometimes it gets too complex that [Laravel's Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#available-validation-rules) can't help, so I make another validation in the data service (which is imported in the Controller).

I'll give an example to make it much clearer:

A writer posts and article. The data request is being processed at `App\Http\Requests\Article\CreateArticleRequest`. After the validation verifies it's valid, the request is being forwarded to the controller. In the controller, I send the request to the `ArticleService` for the business logic. So far so good.

But! what if I want to make some specific validation on my own that Laravel's validation rules can't help me. because then I'll have to load a repository for complex queries.

So the big issue here is that I "double check" the request instead of one time. So I thought about merging my 2 authorization (1 from the \Request and second from my `Service`). But to achieve that, I'll have to load repositories that are bound to their interface. So what's your solution?

Comment: Can't you just add custom validation rules?

Comment: No. I can't because I'm doing complex queries that the only way to load them is from the repository. Only after I load them, I would be able to check if the user is authorized to make that call.

Comment: Can you show us some code you made so far?

Comment: You can have complex custom validation rules that make use of the repository. And it is the correct way to go about it so that the form request can simply worry about authorization and mapping input to the relevant rules.

Comment: @Eitan my "code story" is a bit different, and posting the codes here would be in my opinion irrelevant.

Comment: @nCrazed and how do I exactly achieve that? I need the repositories to only check if the client is authorized to make that request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [extending](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) the validator factory with a new rule you can pass it a closure that inherits (see Example #3 [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)) any dependencies that are required.

So in your case it would be something like this:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $repository = $this->app->make(Repository::class);
    Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) use ($repository) {
        return /* your validation logic */
    });
}
```

As for the authorization you can simply type-hint the necessary dependencies in your authorize method signature:

```php
public function authorize(Repository $repository)
{
    return /* your authorization logic */
}
```

Comment: And what if I want to use the repository to check if the request is authorized/forbidden?